# Rest API - Which has higher priority in a SOQL query, LIMIT clause OR Sforce-Query-Options: batchSize?

Tags: soql, rest-api, soap-api, rest, governorlimits

When a SOQL query has both a `LIMIT clause` and a `Sforce-Query-Options: batchSize` with different but valid values, which one of these gets a higher precedence?

1. A query with only LIMIT clause

```
SELECT ID from foo__c LIMIT 1000
```

2. Another query with a LIMIT clause and the `Sforce-Query-Options: batchSize` header i.e.

```
Sforce-Query-Options: batchSize=250

SELECT ID from foo__c LIMIT 1000
```

The second query with a `batchSize=250` header and limit clause of `1000` only returns 250 records.

Does it mean `batchSize` header has a higher precedence over the `LIMIT clause`?

Answer (score 0):

`batchSize` only affects the number of records returned **per API call**. To get the rest, follow the `nextRecordsUrl` parameter. Note that `batchSize` is only a hint. Actual batch size may be smaller depending on how many, and what type, of fields are requested. In any event, the maximum batch size is 2000, while max limit is 50 million.